# addObject not working with NSMutableSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutableset

I've tried to add an Object to the NSMutableSet but it doesn't work where it perfectly works fine with NSMutableArray.

```
//doesn't Work

[arr_NSMutableSet addObject:Object];
NSLog(@"%@",arr_NSMutableSet); // Shows nil

//Works fine
[arr_NSMutableArray addObject:Object];
NSLog(@"%@",arr_NSMutableArray); // Shows result
```

How to add the Object in NSMutableSet?

Comment: How u r creating `arr_NSMutableSet`?

Comment: once check the initializations. may be you are not initializing it.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I didn't initialized it. So stupid of me :D. Thanx for your comment @ismail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr_NSMutableSet` is nil. You need to create it:

```
arr_NSMutableSet = [NSMutableSet set];
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. It worked perfectly fine. That was my silly mistake :D . And my reputation is below 15 that's why not able to up vote your answer :(

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableSet *brokenCars = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects:
                            @"Honda Civic", @"Nissan Versa", nil];
NSMutableSet *repairedCars = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:5];
// "Fix" the Honda Civic
[brokenCars removeObject:@"Honda Civic"];
[repairedCars addObject:@"Honda Civic"];
```

You can try this

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I didn't initialized it. So stupid of me :D. Thanx for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, created a simple string object and added to the Mutable set like as folows

```
NSMutableSet *customSet = [NSMutableSet set];
NSString *str = @"str";
[customSet addObject:str];
```

Its working for me

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I didn't initialized it. So stupid of me :D. Thanx for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens to me because I forgot to initialize the set (or array, or dictionary...). Make sure you are doing the following:

```
NSMutableSet *mySet = [NSMutableSet set];
```

or, alternatively:

```
NSMutableSet *mySet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
```

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I didn't initialized it. So stupid of me :D. Thanx for your comment :)